# Почему UDP Hole Punching не всегда обходит NAT?

Tags: c#, nat, p2p

Данный код позволяет делать p2p между пользователями, но бывает работает через раз. Тестили с другом, все работает прекрасно. Но как только он пытается сделать тоже самое с другим пользователем, все перестает работать. Может разные типы NAT или еще чего.
Сама программа подключается к STUN-серверу и получает публичные ip. Потом при подключении через сторонний сервеp (используем текстовые сообщения jabber) делаем инициализацию и обмен ip между пользователями. Но что-то идет не так(

```
switch (data.com)
{
case "Call":
   if (MessageBox.Show("Звонок от " + msg.From.Bare, "Входящий", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
   {
   //Была нажата кнопка “Yes”
      string ipp = data.data;  //Получает ip вызывающего пользлвателя
      userEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipp.Substring(0, ipp.IndexOf(":"))),
                                    Convert.ToInt32(ipp.Substring(ipp.IndexOf(":") + 1)));
      UDPMess(); //Отправляем ему UDP пакет
      To = msg.From;
      SentTo(Command.Yes, myEndPoint, msg.From); //Сообщаем серверу что мы ожидаем пользователя и свой ip
      StartVoice(); //Начинаем передачу голоса
   }
   else
   {
      SentTo(Command.No, null, msg.From); //Сообщаем серверу об отказе
   }
   break;
case "Yes":
   //Происходит, если пользователь согласился на передачу и ожидает отклика
   //Все тоже самое только для инициирующей передачу стороны
   string ip = data.data;
   userEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip.Substring(0, ip.IndexOf(":"))),
                                Convert.ToInt32(ip.Substring(ip.IndexOf(":") + 1)));
   UDPMess();
   To = msg.From;
   StartVoice();
   MessageBox.Show("Пользователь " + msg.From.Bare + " принял вызов");
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ответ на "почему": потому что большинство бытовых NAT файрволов, к счастью, реализуют так называемый `restricted cone` или даже `port-restricted cone NAT`, когда пакеты во внутреннюю сеть принимаются для динамически созданного для исходящего пакета сокета только с `IP` адреса (или даже пары `IP:port`), на который был послан исходящий пакет.

Соотвественно, обе стороны в `p2p` сессии должны послать такие исходящие пакеты на хост, который имеет полный контроль над диапазоном используемых портов и способен перенаправлять (проксировать) пакеты противоположной стороне. Это называется TURN, и, хотя на сервер ложится задача проксирования трафика, а сессия получается не вполне p2p, этот подход довольно надёжно используется в IP телефонии.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно используется симметричный NAT. Ну или просто маршутизация UDP реализована корректно, а не абы как. UDP Hole Punching - не стандартная функция, а уязвимость, пусть и периодически эксплуатируемая в благих целях.

Кода у вас вопросе слишком мало - нельзя воспроизвести ситуацию используя только эту часть.

Постарайтесь избавиться от этого, да перейти на обычный проброс портов на маршрутизаторах, либо использовать централизованный сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вместо STUN сервера:

> Traversal Using Relay NAT (TURN) — это протокол, который позволяет узлу за NAT или брандмауэром получать входящие данные через TCP или UDP соединения. Такая возможность особенно актуальна для узлов позади симметричных NAT, или брандмауэров, которые собираются стать принимающей стороной в соединении с одним конкретным узлом (peer-ом). Протокол TURN описан в RFC 5766, обновление TURN для поддержки IPv6 описано в RFC 6156.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?